# How do I renew/revalidate my lapsed JAR PPL?

Tags: pilot-certification, easa, ppl, easa-regulations

I obtained a JAR PPL in 2003 and flew regularly for a few years afterwards. My last flight as Pilot in Command was around 2006 and as I have not kept up the required number of hours per year since then I'm assuming my license will have lapsed.

What do I need to do to regain my PPL? Will I need to retake the exams, the radio telephony license, and the Skills Test?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll have a go at answering this.  It's confused by the UK's transition from the JAA to EASA licensing.

My JAR-PPL(A), issued in 2011, is valid for 5 years so yes, I assume yours will have expired.  My FRTOL is valid for 10 years so presumably yours will have expired too.

The requirements are hidden in [CAP 804](http://www.caa.co.uk/docs/33/CAA_CAP%20804.pdf) ([Deep breath] Section 7, Part B (Schedule 7) Part C, Section 2, Paragraph 9-(1)(c)).  Renewing an expired licence (single-engined/single pilot aeroplane) seems to require meeting FCL.740.A of Part-FCL (type rating) and Appendix 9 to Part–FCL (skills test).

I believe this effectively means you'll have to undertake training to ensure you can pass the skills test, pass it and pay to have your licence reissued.  (Not forgetting the medical.)   You will end-up with a part-FCL PPL (which do not expire).

I'm not sure about having to retake the FRTOL tests, I think you may just have to re-sit the theory (PPL comms), fill out a form and pay but the answer is probably in CAP 804 somewhere!

The easiest/best thing to do would be to pop-in to your local friendly FTO and discuss with them...

Comment: Thank you, good answer and points to the resource I need to read.